# How to build a nested structure with Rails and ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a Feature model that `belongs_to` FeatureKey and FeatureValue.

```
FeatureKey#name => 'color'
FeatureValue#name => 'red'
```

I would like to generate a nested aggregations structure to build a shopping cart filter (facet) navigation.

Ideally, the structure would like something like

```
{ features: {
  { key: color, values: [ red, blue, yellow ] },
  { key: size, values: [ large, medium, small ]}
}}
```

Can anyone anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I'm currently using:

```
{  
    "size":1000,
    "fields":[  
        "id",
        "name",
        "price"
    ],
    "query":{  
        "filtered":{  
            "filter":{  
                "bool":{  
                    "must":[  
                        {  
                            "term":{  
                                "categories":4838
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{  
        "price":{  
            "stats":{  
                "field":"price"
            }
        },
        "discounted":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"discounted"
            }
        },
        "stock":{  
            "filter":{  
                "range":{  
                    "stock":{  
                        "gt":0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "colour":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"colour"
            }
        },
        "size":{  
            "terms":{  
                "field":"size"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add or remove aggregations as you wish. You most likely wish to filter by category, so I left that in for simplicity's sake.